# SQLite картинки и текст

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview, android-textview

Задача состоит в том, что у меня есть Активити, на которой размещены `TextView` и `ImageView`, и я хочу текст с картинками выгружать с базы данных. Приложение не подразумевает подключения к интернету. Подскажите алгоритм действий или примеры, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: изображения можете хранить ,как строки, нипример, предварительно base64Encode их. Или же можете хранить в базе данных путь к файлу изображения. Как хранить текст, я думаю, понятно.

Comment: изображения лучше в БД не хранить. их лучше разместить в папке assets. а в остальном соглашусь с  metalurgus. в БД можно хранить путь, если это необходимо ну и текст.. хотя с текстом тоже вопрос.. проще загружать его с ресурсов string

Answer (score 1):

Если данные (изображения и текст) изменяются в процессе, то ресурсы вам не помогут. 
В базе изображения можно хранить в полях типа "**BLOB**".

Пример скрипта на создание таблицы:

```
    CREATE TABLE table1  
        (_id integer primary key autoincrement,
        name string,
        description string,
        image blob);
```

Только необходимо преобразовать изображение в массив байт, и обратно:

```
 // convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

// convert from byte array to bitmap
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

Соответственно записать изображение можно так:

```
... ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", name);
        cv.put("description", description);
        cv.put("image", BitmapUtils.getBytes(image));...
```

а получить так:

```
 final Cursor c;
    ... BitmapUtils.getImage(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image"))) ...
```

Comment: и сколько интересно занимает картинка в памяти БД?

Comment: В БД картинки хранить крайне не рекомендуется. Если речь идет о изменяемых, подгружаемых картинках, то лучшим выходом будет писать их на SD-карту, а в БД хранить путь.

Comment: Все зависит от размера данных